# error: QApplication: No such file or directory?

Tags: c++, qt, directory

I've been following someone's Youtube playlist of tutorials for Qt.  When I try to follow the [Basic Application and HTML Aware Widgets](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gk3zh5lA4ww), I am getting this error when trying create an empty Qt project with an added c++ class:

```
error: QApplication: No such file or directory
```

I have the latest Qt creator and library installed and its underlining the #includes...

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QLabel *label = new QLabel("hello world");

    label.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

to answer below: I tried that, my .pro looks like this:

QT      += core widgets
SOURCES += main.cpp

and I got these errors..

```
In function 'int qMain(int, char**)':
error: request for member 'show' in 'label', which is of pointer type 'QLabel*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested on KUbuntu with Qt5.0.1

My `.pro` file

```
QT      += core widgets
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

My `main.cpp` file:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);              // QApp... instead of Qapp...
    QLabel *label = new QLabel("hello world"); // QLabel * instead of Qlabel

    label->show();  // <- label-> instead of label.

    return app.exec();
}
```